# I am trying to erase and reformat drive with snow leopard, but don't have the install DVD

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard, install, disk-format, secure-erase

I have a 2009 MacBook Pro running Snow Leopard, and I'm selling it to someone. Want to erase and reformat the drive but I don't have the Snow Leopard Install DVD. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The Apple Store online sells the Snow Leopard Install DVD for approx. $20.
Link provided- http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard or you may need to purchase a replacement DVD that came with your computer. I would call them first.